# How to expand nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I would like to expand `nodeJs` module.

For example, I want to add a function into [Utilities](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html) module.

like detect empty **JSON** object

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  return !Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

So, I can use `util.isEmptyObject()` to detect empty **JSON** object.

Is it a  good way to expand `nodeJs` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend "utils" with defining your "UtilEx" module:

```
/* utils_ex.js */
var utils = require('utils');
utils.isEmptyObject = function() {  };

exports = module.exports = utils;
/* end of utils_ex.js" */

/// client js
var utils = require('utils_ex');
```